# convert string date to milliseconds in android

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I'm having trouble converting the string format date = 2021-05-10T13: 30: 09Z to Date in the android kotlin I tried with the code below but at the time of the conversion ParseException is returned

```
val a = "2021-05-10T13:30:09Z"
    try {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        val date: Date = sdf.parse(a)
    } catch (e: ParseException){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date/60214805#60214805) question is the same.

Your string format is a ISO 8601 format and a nice solution would be something like this:

```kotlin
val ta = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(a)
val i = Instant.from(ta)
val d = Date.from(i)
```